# Can I decrypt a different encoded pdf stream from Azure blob storage than utf-8 with pikepdf?

Tags: python, pdf, azure-blob-storage, pikepdf

I am accessing an encrypted pdf file saved in blob storage on Azure. I get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte` when I run the following code:

```
date = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
dec = "C:/Users/python-test/source_dir/WOTC_DENIALS_Decrypted-{0}.pdf".format(date)

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(constr)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
streamdownloader = blob_client.download_blob().readall()

pdf = pikepdf.Pdf.open(streamdownloader, password=password)
pdf.save(dec)
pdfFileObj = open(dec, 'rb')

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

ending_page = pdfReader.numPages

print("Total number of pages detected accurately? ")
print(pdfReader.numPages)
```

Comment: I am trying to read a stream that I get when I access the pdf file from the blob storage on Azure.

Comment: I need to deploy this app so I am not trying to save the file locally? Is there any other way to decrypt the stream. If not can you write some code and show me how to save the stream as a file and inspect its head. Sorry I am new to python!